# apple mobileconfig edit manually

Tags: ios, xml, pfx, pkcs#12

i am trying to create mobileconfig files manually.
i created one mobileconfig file with apple configurator. this file is the source for all following files.

my problem is now, i dont know how to add/replace manually a pkcs12(pfx) certificate to the mobileconfig file.
the source mobileconfig file contains a private certificate with the key/password.

i want now to replace this certificate with another private one.

under the tag "payloadcontent" is a tag named "data". this tag stores the certificate as base64 encoded in the .mobileconfig file, this is written in apple documentary about payloadcontent.
when i export the pkcs12 certificate with openssl into pem(base64), i get other data shown then in the .mobileconfig file.

so my questions are
1. payloadcontent/data stores pkcs12(pfx), right?
2. why is the data shown unter payloadcontant/data in .mobileconfig file other than the data shown in the convertet pem(base64)?
3. how can i add manually a certificate with private key into the mobileconfig-file?
4. do i even need the private key or does just the certificate work to authenticate to wireless lan?

thanks :)